# How to label connected components (patches) of an image classification with python

Tags: python, r, image, classification, labeling

I have a georeferenced classification (derived from satellite imagery) with values from 1 to 3. I would like to label each connecting patch with a unique number.

e.g.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 2
1 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1
1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

becomes

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3
1 1 2 1 2 2 4 4 1 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 1 1 4 1 1 3
1 5 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 1
1 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6
```

by keeping the class information.

I have tried:

1. "ConnCompLabel" from the "SDMTools" but it works very slow and it would be nice to have a handy solution for this in python.
2. sckit comand "measure.lable" as recommended in this post "https://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html" but I don't want to lose the geospatial information.

Could I use rasterio and flood fill algorithms?

I need this for computing Satial Metrics for each patch separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the spatial reference system by adding it again after labeling.

```
# Labeling and losing geospatial information:
Classification= imageio.imread("C:/path/to/Classification/raster.tif") # read Classification 
labeled_Classifiation = measure.label(Classification, background=0) # label Classification

# steps for adding geospatial information:
labeled_Classifiation = np.array(ndci_EM_polished_labels)

dataset=gdal.Open(r"C:/path/to/Classification/raster.tif")
projection = dataset.GetProjection()
geo_transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dst_ds = drv.Create("C:/path/to/result/name_of_labeled_Classifiation.tif",
                    labeled_Classifiation.shape[1],
                    labeled_Classifiation.shape[0],
                                1,
                                gdal.GDT_Float32, ['COMPRESS=DEFLATE',
                                                   'BIGTIFF=YES',
                                                   'PREDICTOR=1',
                                                   'TILED=YES'])
dst_ds.SetProjection(projection)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(labeled_Classifiation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the scikit-image command this way:

- Split the image into 3 different binary images by setting values different from 1 to 0 for the first image, eg

  ```
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
  1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
  1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  ```

Same thing for 2 and 3

- Apply the scikit command on each image
- Shift the values so they won't mix and reconstitute the image

Have I correctly understood your problem ?

Comment: I have formulated this imprecisely, the labeling worked with the scikit-image. The problem with this approach is, that the spatial reference information gets lost.
I try now to extract the spatial reference system from the original classification and project it to the labeled one but I wonder if there is already a better possibility.